# Opencart Login Issues

Tags: opencart2.x

I am unable to login to the Opencart Dashboard. I can see the login screen and enter passwords. I even did a fresh install. It just doesn't redirect me to the dashboard. I have read up and tried every possible solution. Is there something on the server that could be blocking the re-direct.

Comment: -Hello? -Honey, my car won't start! What's the problem?

Comment: Well commented @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by .htaccess redirect. It happened to me too because my website was getting redirected to www.example.com but the session was for example.com. Make sure you have the same version of the url everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked in both my config files, the URL is all the same. Where else could I look to see if it is different.

Comment: Please provide your url. It is hard to understand what's going on without seeing any code or a live URL.